# Crystal Reports - HTML in textfields - Background color

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I want to use HTML in Crystal Reports. I already found out Crystal reports renders some HTML tags nicely (at least the few tags they support).

Html like this works:

```
 <b>Bold and <i>italic</i> and <font color="#ff0000">colored</font> text.</b>
```

Now I want to render a background color for my text (which is a pretty common kind of rich text formatting), and I remember I have Crystal already seen renderering it, but I cannot remember the HTML to tell crystal. I believe it could be done with the style attribute, but using `style="background-color:#ff0000"` is not recognized.

How can I tell Crystal to give me some background color? Or doesn't this work anymore since CR 2008?

**EDIT:**

I want to use a HTML string displayed in a normal text control with the "text interpretation" attribute set to HTML. And my HTML simply does not work! I just need one example HTML line that make Crystal Report (2008 here) display a different background color for a word, and all my tries that work well in browsers, are not understood by Crystal.

I know how to set bold, the foreground color, different font sizes, underlined, etc., but I just do not get the background color to work. So **the answer to this question is simply a simple String of HTML**.

Comment: what version of CR?  can you post the entire html string (i can test in v2008)?  i this text embedded in a text object (so only part of the text object's text will have a background color)?

Comment: @craig: I want to use a HTML string displayed in a normal text control with the "text interpretation" attribute set to HTML. And my HTML simply does not work! I just need one example HTML line that make Crystal Report (2008 here) display a different background color for a word, and all my tries that work well in browsers, are not understood by Crystal. I know how to set bold, the foreground color, different font sizes, underlined, etc., but I just do not get the background color to work. So the answer to this question is simply a simple String of HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply does not work. Stupid Crystal... we are migrating to Jasper Reports right now. For this and a bag of other reasons. Everyone in my company is hating Crystal Reports now.